# CSS not working on 2 DIV tags when I add display: inline;

Tags: html, css

So I am creating a code compiler with two buttons:
RUN and DOWNLOAD. But instead of using `<button>` tags, I use `<div>` tags so that I can have a more variety of CSS styles for my buttons. But the problem is, when I try to make the second button by copying and pasting the same code from the RUN button, the DOWNLOAD button is underneath the RUN button when I needed them on the same line.

So, I added the `display: inline;` style but that just messed up everything and the styles for the div didn't work. The only styles that worked were the styles for the text in the div buttons and that centered the text to the middle of the page.
Here is the code:

```css
.dbutton,
.button {
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px gray;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.btn-text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.dbtn-text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.dbutton:hover,
.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.dbutton:active,
.button:active {
  background-color: #00ad08;
}

div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <p class="btn-text">
    Run &gt;&gt;
  </p>
</div>

<div class="dbutton">
  <p class="dbtn-text">
    Download &darr;
  </p>
</div>
```

If you want the full code, here is the link.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPizzaGuy/dxvjmLhr/76/)

The two divs are not styling and the text in the buttons are placed in the middle of the page. I need the two divs to be beside each other and the for the style to work. Please help me!

Comment: That is the code inside of the textarea

Comment: Wrapping the buttons in a container makes this easier. You could then use floats or in the case of the example I created, flex properties: https://jsfiddle.net/p49f7kvb/6/

Comment: Don't change `display` for all `div` tags. This would be a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.btn-bar {
  position:relative
  /* ... */
}
.btn {
  float:left;
  background:red;
  width:7em;
  padding:11px 3px;
  margin:3px;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-bar">
  <div class="btn">run</div>
  <div class="btn">compile</div>
</div>
```